# How to add vertical scroll only for selected div inside bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 `div` in bootstrap modal separated by `col-8` and `col-4`.Here how can I add vertical scroll only for `col-4` div?

```css
/* .addScroll{
  overflow-y:auto;
} */
/* .modal-body{
 overflow-y:auto;
} */
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="col-xs- 8 col-sm-8  col-md-8 col-lg-8">In 1980, physicist Tim Berners-Lee, a contractor at CERN, proposed and prototyped ENQUIRE, a system for CERN researchers to use and share documents. In 1989, Berners-Lee wrote a memo proposing an Internet-based hypertext system. Berners-Lee specified HTML and wrote the browser and server software in late 1990.</div>
                    <div class="col-xs- 4 col-sm-4  col-md-4 col-lg-4 addScroll">In 1980, physicist Tim Berners-Lee, a contractor at CERN, proposed and prototyped ENQUIRE, a system for CERN researchers to use and share documents. In 1989, Berners-Lee wrote a memo proposing an Internet-based hypertext system. Berners-Lee specified HTML and wrote the browser and server software in late 1990.</div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can add `vertical-scroll` for complete `modal-body`. But I want to add only for `col-4` div. Any suggestion?

https://jsfiddle.net/et5b274h/

Comment: You can do that by adding fixed height to .addScroll element and then adding overflow-y:auto

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `.addScroll` div inside `.col-sm-4` div set height of it with overflow-y element

```css
.addScroll{
  overflow-y:auto;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs- 8 col-sm-8  col-md-8 col-lg-8">In 1980, physicist Tim Berners-Lee, a contractor at CERN, proposed and prototyped ENQUIRE, a system for CERN researchers to use and share documents. In 1989, Berners-Lee wrote a memo proposing an Internet-based hypertext system. Berners-Lee specified HTML and wrote the browser and server software in late 1990.</div>
                        <div class="col-xs- 4 col-sm-4  col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                            <div class=" addScroll">
                                In 1980, physicist Tim Berners-Lee, a contractor at CERN, proposed and prototyped ENQUIRE, a system for CERN researchers to use and share documents. In 1989, Berners-Lee wrote a memo proposing an Internet-based hypertext system. Berners-Lee specified HTML and wrote the browser and server software in late 1990.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following CSS rules:

```
.addScroll {
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 140px;
}
```

If you will not specify `height` or `max-height` of `.addScroll` element (or one of the parent elements will not limit its height), it will take as much height as content, and the scroll will not be applied. But if you will specify for example `max-height: 140px;` (the same height as the other `div`), the scroll will be applied.

Here is the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/et5b274h/1/

Answer (score 3):

Please check https://jsfiddle.net/et5b274h/8/ and see if this is what you want. I have added a **div** with class **row** inside modal-content.

```
<div class="container">

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-ld-8 col-xs-8">
                  11one one one one one one one one

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-ld-4 col-xs-4">
                  <div style="width: 100%; height: 100px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden">
                    22two
                    <br/> two
                    <br/> two
                    <br/> two
                    <br/> two
                    <br/> two
                    <br/> two two two
                  </div>
                  <div>

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CSS` `overflow-y: scroll;height: 120px` to your inner `div`(`col-md-4`).

If you use `auto` instead of `scroll` it will add scroll whenever necessary.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="col-xs- 8 col-sm-8  col-md-8 col-lg-8">In 1980, physicist Tim Berners-Lee, a contractor at CERN, proposed and prototyped ENQUIRE, a system for CERN researchers to use and share documents. In 1989, Berners-Lee wrote a memo proposing an Internet-based hypertext system. Berners-Lee specified HTML and wrote the browser and server software in late 1990.</div>
           <div style="overflow-y: scroll;height: 120px;" class="col-xs- 4 col-sm-4  col-md-4 col-lg-4 vertical-scroll addScroll">In 1980, physicist Tim Berners-Lee, a contractor at CERN, proposed and prototyped ENQUIRE, a system for CERN researchers to use and shar CERN researchers to use and shar CERN researchers to use and shar CERN researchers to use and share documents. In 1989, Berners-Lee wrote a memo proposing adsfdsfdsfdsfdsfsdfds edsfsdfn Internet-based hypertext system. Berners-Lee specified HTML and wrote the browser and server software in late 1990.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```